# Not able to install any module using NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new for node.js . When i'm install any module in my project folder i got this type of error. There is some path problem or something else .

**Please help**

Error on cmd --

```
C:\node1>npm install connect

npm WARN package.json underscore@1.1.6 No README data
npm WARN package.json underscore@1.1.6 No license field.
npm WARN package.json underscore@1.1.6 specifying dependencies as array is depre
cated
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "connect"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: did you try this https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=errno+EAI_AGAIN&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=wgWNVeyECszbU833g-AK#q=npm+errno+EAI_AGAIN

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Try some other module to cross check

`EAI_AGAIN` actually means a temporary failure in name resolution or simply the name server returned a temporary failure indication. It will ask you to try again later.

[image]

Comment: Thanks karthick, but i tried  mostly module ,but same error occur.